# Manipulate dataframe with pandas to transpose columns and adjust dates?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, transpose

How can I manipulate a dataframe like this, making a transpose that joins one under the other and arranges it in the form of dates?

Let it be by transforming this existing dataframe, without messing with its creation.

**Dataframe:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Jan':[1, 2, 3],
        'Feb':[4, 5, 6],
        'Mar':[7, 8, 9]
    })
df
```

**Output:**

```
    Jan Feb Mar
0   1   4   7
1   2   5   8
2   3   6   9
```

**Desired Result:**

```
        
1990-Jan    1       
1990-Feb    4   
1990-Mar    7   
1991-Jan    2   
1991-Feb    5   
1991-Mar    8
1992-Jan    3   
1992-Feb    6   
1992-Mar    9
```

obs: In the final result the dates don't have to be the name of the months, it can be their number.

Comment: It sounds like you want to unpivot, but what determines the year? Is it 1990 + row index?

Comment: The year is to be determined manually, like, set the initial year to be 2002 and then change the first index to 2002, then the others to 2003, 2004, and so on. The current index serves nothing but order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# flatten the DF
df2=df.stack().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'val'})

# create the date
df2['date'] = (1990 + df2['level_0']).astype('str') + "-" + df2['level_1']

# drop unwanted columns
df2=df2.drop(columns=['level_0','level_1'])
df2
```

```
    val     date
0   1   1990-Jan
1   4   1990-Feb
2   7   1990-Mar
3   2   1991-Jan
4   5   1991-Feb
5   8   1991-Mar
6   3   1992-Jan
7   6   1992-Feb
8   9   1992-Mar
```